# Getting querystring parameter value in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, query-string

I'm making a wordpress plugin. I've used add_query_string() inside anchors in order to load content based on what link the user has clicked. Now I need to know the best way to get the parameter value in the current URI.

It's probably a pretty basic and stupid question, but I'm new to programming so I'm sorry if I misinterpret some terms.

This is the code:

```
        if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
            echo (
                '<div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="'.add_query_arg( 'adminoption', 1 ).'">option 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="'.add_query_arg( 'adminoption', 2 ).'">option 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>'
            );

            // if adminoption == 1 load content A
            // if adminoption == 2 load content B

        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you are asking for [get_query_var()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) function.
In your case you should use get_query_var('adminoption').
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks David. Nice suggestion, but that returned blank for me.

Truth is I don't even know if I should be using add_query_arg().

All I need to do is to show content on the same page depending on query string. I could just create one page for each link but that's not an option as I'd not be learning anything, and learning is the main reason I'm messing with creating a plugin.

Comment: What is your url like after you click on a link? 
Is it something like www.yoursite.com/?adminoption=1

Just to know if your problem starts on add_query_arg().
Anyway you may try with the old php $_GET['adminoption'].

Comment: Yes, the URL after clicking on a link is fine. And $_GET['adminoption'] worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch! Do I have to worry about security while using $_GET though?

Comment: I suppose you are only showing a content based on the argument and not putting the value inside a DB query, nor using it on page directly, so you shouldn't have any problem. 

I suppose Wp uses a function to retrieve values, for security reasons, adding controls and sanitizing them but this shouldn't be the case. 

Strange that the WP function doesn't work. 
Did you get any error? or just a blank value? What kind of page is the one where you are writing the code?

Comment: Just plain blank value. Could it be the scope I'm calling it from? The code is inside a static function.

Comment: Don't assume that $_GET is safe, even if you're not putting the value into a DB. You may still be vulnerable to cross site scripting, i.e. someone inserting malicious code into you page via a GET parameter.

Comment: This seems doesn't work for custom query vars. Just try @Reine Johansson solution

Answer (score 18):

get_query_var('adminoption') only works with standard or registered vars. So for non-standard Wordpress vars you would need to register it first in your functions.php file:

```
function rj_add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "adminoption";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'rj_add_query_vars_filter' );

get_query_var('adminoption');
```

Realize the question is old but hope it helps anyone.

Comment: What are you adding "group" to the `$vars[]` array? Shouldn't it be `$vars[] = "adminoption";`?

Answer (score 14):

Raising hidden answer in the comments by David Carrus:

> Anyway you may try with the old php $_GET['adminoption'].

Answer (score 10):

To get a vars from the query string you can use PHP's `$_GET['key']` method.

Depending on what you are doing, you can also use `get_query_var('key')`, [this function works with parameters accepted by the WP_Query class (cat, author, etc)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/#more-information).

If you want to use custom query vars with this function, you need to use the [query_vars](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/) filter to modify the list of supported query vars, you can read how to do that in the documentation linked above.

Comment: +1 surprisingly `get_query_var('key')` doesn't work with custom arguments and this is the only answer that mentions it